# How to show only error message oracle raise application error

Tags: oracle, error-handling, triggers, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing oracle triggers and i have some error messages.

I use this code for handling error:

```
raise_application_error(-20001, 'error message, please do not this');
```

But this shows very lot info; 
For example:

```
ora-20001: <<custom message>>. 
ora-06512: at <<package.procedure_name>>, line 100
```

I want only show error message body: "error message, please do not this"

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I found this question pretty high in my Google search, here is a simple method to just get the error message:

```
declare
  procedure test is
  begin
    raise_application_error(-20222, 'This is an error');
  end test;
begin
  test;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(replace(sqlerrm, 'ORA' || sqlcode || ': ', ''));
end;
```

Will output:

> This is an error

Answer (score 1):

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SQLERRM, '^ORA-[0-9]+: ', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SQLERRM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlerrm_function.htm) function, which will return the exception number and the message, without the lines. There's no function for returning only the text, but you can use SQLCODE function to do that like the second example in [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_sqlerrm.htm).

Just remember that this data is mainly intended to help you to cope with unexpected situations in debugging, logging, etc., so most of the time you should consider writing all of the exception info to your log.